# Como pueden hacerse calculos en vb y mostrar muchos decimales

Tags: vb.net, vb

Necesito una alta precisión de decimales. Como puedo conseguir mas de los que da una variable decimal?

Comment: Cuanto de alta? Una posible solución es usar BigInteger y gestionar tu los decimales(multiplicar por x para que no queden decimales, operar y luego dividir por x de nuevo). El rendimiento no será muy bueno probablemente, pero depende de exactamente cuales son tus necesidades

Comment: calcular tantos decimales de pi como sean posibles

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11679007/579895

Answer (score 0):

Las Largadas Decimales de las Variables del Sistema No Supera los Números de Más de 64BITS Por Defecto...
Para Usar Variables Más Largas Necesitas Usar Variables Que Si lo Soporten Como String Pero Has de Crear Tu Los Métodos Para Llegar a Más Precisión... Es algo bastante complejo de explicar , Yo estoy en eso y llevo dos años para hacer lo que pides...
Aquí Te Dejo un Ejemplo de lo Más Amplio Que Se le Puede Hacer con el Sistema, Ya Que el Cómo Se Hace es Bastante Largo de Explicar ( Ocupa 4000 Líneas de Códigos )...

```
'Usa Variables Double en Vez de Single
    
    Dim Variable As Double = 1.666666666666667

    MsgBox(Variable)
```